# Elementor Pro: How to add responsive content to accordion

Tags: wordpress, accordion, elementor, posts

Before I explain the problem, let me provide the context. I would like to use an accordion to contain 4 audio book reviews (very short reviews, more like a few words as to why the user should listen to it) for the current week. Each week, I will review 4 new audio books but I would like to retain the previous week's content for SEO purposes and to enrich my site content. I plan to add the fresh reviews to the top of the accordion each week.

I am trying to create content that will display correctly within an Elementor Pro accordion (i.e. so that it will behave responsively when viewed on smaller devices.)

I can see that Elementor Pro does not allow me to add elements within the accordion, so as a work around I have tried creating a template which looks like the following:

[Elementor Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHvM.png)

Then on the page where my accordion is located, I then simply paste the shortcode into the accordion and I get the desired result.

[View of published accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrBwo.png)

**The problem:**

Because I am creating new content, it doesn't feel right to be creating a new template each week but I am unsure of the alternative. Also, I'm not sure I would get the SEO benefits if all the content was contained within templates.

If I use posts, and create a new post for each audio book 'review' (which feels like the right thing to do), I have issues when displaying the content:

[Image displayed as a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Enh.png)

1. Because I am displaying the post's featured image and the excerpt, I cannot see how to add the "listen on Spotify" button underneath.
2. I don't actually want the user to be able to navigate to the post. So is it possible to disable the ability to click the header and the image?

Any advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you can answer like you are explaining this to a four year old it would be good because I am pretty new to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by creating a new Custom Post Type. For this you can use CPTUI. Install Advance Custom Fields 7 to make custom fields in the Custom Post Type.

After this, install Ele custom skin plugin. This plugin will help you to create a new layout for the showcase of Custom post type if you don't want to use the elementor's ordinary post item grid.

After this, by using the Elemetors theme builder, you can create the layout of the inner pages for your new Custom post type.